# Angular Google Maps not displaying in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, angular-ui

I'm using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) to implement a map and geo-location in my [Ionic](http://www.ionicframework.com) app. I do everything according to the docs, but the map isn't displaying (even though there isn't any console output showing errors).

**Controller**:

```
app.controller('panicController', ['$scope', '$cordovaGeolocation',
  function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation) {

    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };

  }
]);
```

**View**:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" ng-controller="panicController" class="panic-view">

  <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true" class="padding">

    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

**SCSS**:

```
.angular-google-map-container { 
  height: 100%; 
}
```

When I run it, I just get a blank/empty white view. And my console output:

[image]

Any idea of what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you try giving also a width property? Also in the documents it has 400px of height. Maybe 100% height doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example can help you.`_`
[nightly codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt)

I used this example in my application too and I like the way.

Do you need to develop it this way?

Greetz,

Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the sensor parameter. But according to the docs, it should not affect the API's behavior. It looks like there's something else going on that shows you the white view.

From the Google Maps API Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages

> **SensorNotRequired**: The sensor parameter is no longer required for the
>   Google Maps JavaScript API. It won't prevent the Google Maps
>   JavaScript API from working correctly, but we recommend that you
>   remove the sensor parameter from the script element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to `explicitly` specify dependency to [uiGmapgoogle-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) via `module`, so make sure `uiGmapgoogle-maps`module is included:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KFaDW3afoCH30NHq68bJ?p=preview)